# jpeg image format not supported by picasso or glide

Tags: android, gridview, imageview, picasso, android-glide

Picasso and Glide aren't supporting/loading image URL with .jpeg extension within image view.

I am working in grid view where image is being loaded in image view , either by picasso or by glide but it isn't supporting the URL with .jpeg extension.

Are there any alternates available?

`Glide.with(getActivity())
                    .load("https://abc/profile.jpeg")
                    .centerCrop()
                    .placeholder(logo)
                    .into(imageView);`

```
Picasso.get()
                .load("https://abc/profile.jpeg")
                .placeholder(R.drawable.logo)
                .error(R.drawable.logo)
                .into(imageView);
```

Comment: what are the error logs for not loading ?

Comment: @VivekMishra there aren't any errors or crashes....simply image is not loading...it picks up placeholder image but not loading the main image

Comment: set the loading listener for glide and then you will be able to see the error logs

Comment: @VivekMishra can u confirm me a thing that url with jpeg extension is supported by glide ?

Comment: I haven't paid attention to the urls but it should work for jpg as well as pngs

Comment: It's not a matter of .jpeg format, it should be from something else. Set a listener for picasso and print the error log.

Comment: I am sure, you would have tested the url directly in browser and also confirmed that it loads properly in normal browser.

Comment: @VivekMishra png formats are working properly....there is something with .jpeg's

Comment: @SHS yeah i did that too and its working on normal browser

Comment: @chachu Is it possible by you to share a non working .jpeg in glide. So possible for others to find cause.

Answer (score -1):

Change the extension of images to .jpg and it'll work.

Comment: it isnt working this way too....i am receiving this URL from an api and if i change the extension to jpg it gives error

Comment: You will need to change the extension of the images also. And make sure your url is correct.